# Componente vue no funciona en vista home(auth-laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, component, auth

Tengo un componente de vue que se renderiza en la vista home del auth de laravel pero no funciona e incluso no me deja cerrar sesion, probándola en otra vista fuera del login  de laravel funciona correctamente

```
**Esta es una vista cualquiera donde funciona mi crud correctamente al llamarlo**

    <body>
     <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        <div class="content"> 
            <div id="app">
                <example-component>           
                </example-component>         
            </div>
            <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
        </div> 

    </div>
</body>
```

**Este es el componente en mi vista home autenticada en laravel (donde falla la funcionalidad)**

```
<main class="py-4">
            {{-- @yield('content') --}}
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        
             <div class="content">              
                 <div id="app">
                     <example-component>
                     </example-component>                              
                 </div>
             </div> 
        </div>
        </main>
    </div>
         <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

Utilice la plantilla layout(yield) pero igual usando el section('content') en mi vista home tampoco funciono, asi que mejor la copie y pegue directamente la plantilla, espero que me ayuden y **no me da ningun error en consola ni en el log de laravel y en las vue tools solo aparece root**

Comment: No sé la respuesta pero sumarte que es raro dónde ubicas el archivo app.js, normalmente va en el head.

Comment: No tendrás otra etiqueta con id="app" por ahí?

Comment: Si no funciona, entonces cómo es eso de que no puedes cerrar sesión? En alguna parte debe funcionar para poder iniciar esa sesion que luego no puedes cerrar, no?